# Is it harm to the car paint if I wash & wax my car 3 times per week?

Tags: paint, carwash, wax

I usually clean my car 3 times a week using water and a sponge.

Today I bought this product which is a wax and shampoo at the same time @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2RGch4dgoA . So my question is; if i can use this product regularly when i wash my car (3 times a week)?

Comment: Please don't use all caps; they're seen as shouting and are impolite here.

Comment: No idea. I wash my car once every five years, whether it needs it or not :) The video gives no information at all about the product so far as I can tell.

Comment: @alephzero five years ot five days!

Comment: The guy in the video is wiping the waxy stuff over the windscreen, which to me is a complete no-no, really dangerous because when it rains, the wipers smear the windscreen and you can't see a thing. I have never waxed my cars, and the paint has never suffered for the lack of it.

Comment: I think 5 years is too long; I try to wash every year.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. Wash and wax all-in-one products will not harm original car paint. Most vehicles have a clear coat over the paint color. Normal driving and exposure creates microscopic pits while dirt chips and becomes embedded into the surface. Regular washing and waxing forms a temporary coating to protect against weathering. When water slides off car surfaces easily, the wax seals the microscopic pitting on clear coat. Wax is temporary and wears off.